# Why the function address is different before and after I run the code?

Tags: c, gdb, function-address

the source code is here

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(a, b) {
  if (b == 0) return a;
  return gcd(b, a % b);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int a = atoi(argv[1]);
  int b = atoi(argv[2]);
  int res = gcd(a, b);
  printf("%d\n", res);
  return 0;
}
```

and compiled with `gcc -O0 gcd.c -o gcd -g`

Before I run gcd, the `gcd()` address is `0x1169`.
After I run it, the address of the same function becomes to `0x555555555169`.

```
$ gdb -q gcd
Reading symbols from gcd...

(gdb) p gcd
$1 = {int (int, int)} 0x1169 <gcd>

(gdb) run 42 24
Starting program: ~/Workstation/gcd 42 24
6
[Inferior 1 (process 104126) exited normally]

(gdb) p gcd
$2 = {int (int, int)} 0x555555555169 <gcd>
```

Why there're such a difference between before and after running the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Movement of \`main\` function after running in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873573/movement-of-main-function-after-running-in-gdb)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I think it not really answer the question, why the address relocated after execution?

Comment: Here’s another answer that goes into more detail. [Why do the addresses in my assembler dump differ from the addresses of registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53311089/2554472)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you so much, this is exactly what I want to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). In short, it means that modules/libs/executables will be at a different address each time being loaded.

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand it, I mean as it want to do ASLR for protection, but why it reveals the real address after running the code?

Comment: because your were using a debugger to inspect it.

Comment: It's not address space randomization, rather position independent executables, that are the problem here.  By default GDB turns off address space randomization.